# Herencia en javascript con prototypes

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Quería saber cuales son las diferencias entre `prototype` y `__proto__`, en que casos se usa cada uno, como funciona la herencia y cuales serían las buenas practicas creando y utilizando objetos en javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Antes que nada hay que entender la diferencia entre una y otra cosa. El `prototype` esta solo presente en funciones, mientras que el `__proto__` esta presente en todos los objetos incluyendo las funciones. Adicional hay que entender que el `__proto__` funciona como referencia y no como instancia, es decir que para efectos de trabajar en algo de orientación a objetos todos los objetos que le añadas el objeto `__proto__` estaran enlazados al mismo. Para muestra un botón:

```
// Implementacion con __proto__
let Humano = {
  edad: 0,
  tipo_cabello: 'rizado'
};
let persona1 = {
  nombre: 'Juan'
};
// Delegando objeto, esto no es una instanciacion
Object.setPrototypeOf(persona1, Humano);
// Ahora puedes hacer
console.log(persona1.edad);
-> 0
// Pero lo que obtienes es esto a cambio
Humano.edad = 1;
console.log(persona1.edad);
-> 1
// Porque persona1 solo tiene como __proto__ (objeto base) a Humano
persona1.__proto__
-> Object {edad: 0, tipo_cabello: "rizado"}
```

Diferente a como funciona el prototype:

```
// Crea una clase por medio de una funcion
function Perro() {}
Dog.prototype.ladrido = 'ruff';
Dog.prototype.ladrar = function() { console.log(this.ladrido) };
// Instancia esta clase
let doggie = new Perro();
let duke = new Perro();
// Ahora puedes hacer uso de la clase
doggie.ladrar();
-> 'ruff'
// Y si obtienes una instancia
doggie.ladrido = 'atchu';
doggie.ladrar();
-> 'atchu'
duke.ladrar();
-> 'ruff'
```

La implementacion correcta de clases e instancias seria mediante funciones y el uso de `new` para crear las nuevas instancias. Te recomiendo veas lo siguiente:

- http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Function

Answer (score 1):

`__proto__` es la referencia al prototipo del objeto.

`prototype` es la referencia al prototipo que tendrá cualquier objeto creado con esa función.

```
var Animal = function () {};
var perro = new Animal();

// Modifica el prototipo de perro.
perro.__proto__.sonido = 'guau'; 

// Modifica el prototipo de los objetos creados con Animal.
Animal.prototype.hablar = function () { console.log(this.sonido); };

perro.hablar(); // Muestra 'guau' en la consola.
```